# how to can loop through an array of array in a json object in python

Tags: python

https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/blob/ff24ab221faaec455b664ad5bbdc6e0de76c3caf/data/countries_data.json

how can i loop through this `countries_data.json` file (see link above) to get 'languages'

i have tried:

```
import json
f  = open("countries_data.json")
file = f.read() 
# print(file)
for item in file:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have everything correct and set up but you didn't load the json file. Also there is a double space on "f = open". You also didn't open the file with the read parameter, not too sure if its needed though.
Correct code:

```
import json
f = open("countries_data.json", "r")
file = json.loads(f.read())

for item in file:
    print(item)
```

Hope this helped, always double check your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one essential step, which is parsing the JSON data to Python datastructures.

```
import json
# read file
f = open("countries.json")
# parse JSON to Python datastructures
countries = json.load(f)
# now you have a list of countries
print(type(countries))

# loop through list of countries
for country in countries:
    # you can access languages with country["languages"]; JSON objects are Python dictionaries now
    print(type(country))
    for language in country["languages"]:
        print(language)
f.close()
```

Expected output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
Pashto
Uzbek
Turkmen
...
```

Comment: how can i Read the countries_data.json data file in data directory, and create a function that finds the ten most spoken languages

Comment: Loop through all the languages and put them in a dictionary `language_count`. If you have not encountered a language before add it to the dictionary like so `language_count["German"] = 1`. If you have encountered it before get value of the language and increase it by one `language_count["German"] += 1`. At the end you will have a count of all languages which you only then need to sort. See [this](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-12.php) for a similar example.

Comment: how do i put them into a dictionary after looping

Answer (score 0):

You can see that you import the `json` module at the beginning, so you might as well use it
If you go to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/json.html) you will see a function allowing you to read this file directly.
In the end you end up with just a dictionary list, the code can be summarized as follows.

```py
import json

with open("test/countries_data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for item in data:
    print(item["languages"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json` built-in package to deserialize the content of that file.

A sample of usage

```
data = """[
{
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "languages": [
            "Pashto",
            "Uzbek",
            "Turkmen"
        ],
        "population": 27657145,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
        "currency": "Afghan afghani"
    },
    {
        "name": "Åland Islands",
        "capital": "Mariehamn",
        "languages": [
            "Swedish"
        ],
        "population": 28875,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
        "currency": "Euro"
    }]"""


# deserializing
print(json.loads(data))
```

For more complex content have a look to the `JSONDecoder`.

[doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

EDIT:

```
import json

path = # my file

with open(path, 'r') as fd:
    # iterate over the dictionaries
    for d in json.loads(fd.read()):
        print(d['languages'])
```

EDIT: extra - top 10 languages

```
import json
import itertools as it

path = # path to file
with open(path, 'r') as fd:
    text = fd.read()

languages_from_file = list(it.chain(*(d['languages'] for d in json.loads(text))))
# get unique "list" of languages
languages_all = set(languages_from_file)
# count the repeated languages
languages_count = {l: languages_from_file.count(l) for l in languages_all}
# order them per descending value
top_ten_languages = sorted(languages_count.items(), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[:10]
print(top_ten_languages)
```

Comment: how can i Read the countries_data.json data file in data directory, and create a function that finds the ten most spoken languages

Comment: follow the answers, use a context manager to open the file, pass it to `json.loads`. `json.loads` returns a list of dictionaries so iterate it and use the `languages` key to access to its content

Comment: Read the countries_data.json data file in data directory, create a function that creates a list of the ten most populated countries